# Write a script to click a button on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome

There is a Google Chrome extension called "Pandora to Spotify Playlist Converter" which grabs your Pandora likes, extracts the name and artist, and finds the Spotify links for them.

The only problem is that Pandora only shows five of your liked songs at a single time. To display more, you have to click the button "Show More" which displays only five more songs. The extension only works when the songs titles are loaded and displayed onto the webpage. So herein lies my problem.

I have 235 likes, which means that I'd have to click the "Show More" button 47 times, which means that if I click the button, scroll down, and click it again (which takes about two seconds), it'd take me a little over a minute and a half of tedious work. Why not write a script that can do this in seconds?

I've looked at other posts and see than many answers include the use of "Selenium," an IDE integrated into Firefox. The problem there is that the Google Chrome extension only exists for Chrome; there is no Firefox add-on that does the same thing. Does anyone know of a way I can go about this, and possibly using Javascript or Python to accomplish it?

Comment: I have to wonder about the utility of spending hours programming something to save a minute and a half...

Comment: @TheSoundDefense Haha, I'd much rather spend half an hour learning to write a simple script than to do backbreaking work that a four year old could do (which I would've done if I had a four year old to do it for me). Plus, in the future, I don't want to have to do the same thing.

Comment: So JJ, did you wrote the easy script?

Answer (score 0):

Well with python i assume you could do this with the [mechanize module](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/)
Here's a [tutorial](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/cheatsheet/python-mechanize-cheat-sheet)